# How to distinguish the certificate, When using the same Ca,

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm admin and I have a developer. I have a CA root certificate (ca & ca.pub) and many servers. I put ca.pub on all the servers. I wanna do the thing that developer can only log in to one server, not to other servers.
How should I sign certificates with ca and configure sshd_config？

For example, if i just sign user.pub with my ca and generate user-cert.pub on a server and send it to developer, then he can use user-cert.pub to all my servers, cz all my servers has trusted ca.pub, that's not what i want!!!

Comment: Probably https://security.stackexchange.com/ is a better place for this question

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to stackoverflow, now i find a great community.

Answer (score 0):

you can distinguish the certificates by the dates of creation and expiration that which certificate is latest and which one is old, if further there is confusion , just remove all certificates and make a new certificate and edit existing all provisioning profiles with new certificates, and you are ready to use new certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!!! Sign certificate with roles, make serverid as role name.

1. Add directory auth_principals in /etc/ssh/, create a file 'root' and add serverid in it.
2. Add AuthorizedPrincipalsFile /etc/ssh/auth_principals/%u into sshd_config, restart sshd!!!

In this way, different servers has different certificate even though they trust same ca.pub.